# List of string variable in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a simple pipeline to deploy my test azure functions, I can't figure out why my list of strings in the variable throws this error:

```
A sequence was not expected
```

Below is the code that generates the error.

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
  functionNames:       
    - 'Function1'
    - 'Function2'

stages:
- template: ../Stage/build-stage.yml
  parameters:
    functionNames: $( functionNames )
```

I tried to review the formatting, location, name but nothing as if it doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Pipelines only supports "string" variables, no arrays or lists.

You can split the text on a delimiter or parse it as json to get something that resembles what you want.